# SQL Server - Using JSON to return Column Names

Tags: sql-server, json, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following test query I'm needing to make dynamic.

Basically a stored procedure will be passed @json and it needs to return the column names that are passed in that variable.

Is this possible and how could I do it?

```
declare @json varchar(max)

set @json = '["FirstName", "LastName","DOB"]';  

select *   
from OPENJSON( @json )  

select
FirstName,
LastName,
DOB
from Client
```

I do have this that works, but not sure on whether it's a good option and whether there's a better way

```
declare @json varchar(max)
declare @columnames varchar (200)
declare @sqlquery nvarchar(200)

set @json = '["FirstName", "LastName","DOB"]';  
set @columnames =''

select @columnames = 
    case when @columnames = ''
    then value
    else @columnames + coalesce(',' + value, '')
    end
  from OPENJSON( @json )  

set  @sqlquery = 'select ' + @columnames + ' from Client'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sqlquery
```

Basically the @json variable can contain one or many or all of the below fields and over-time even more.

```
set @json = '["FirstName", "LastName","DOB","DrugName,"Age","AgeGroup","Overdose","VerificationCode","Gender"]';
```

Comment: Best way is parse data in application. Best practice on sqlserver is create CLR TVL function with deserialization - this function in non-deterministic and you have to use generic code in your app. In this json example string you can use working with strings, but you can have much more complicated strings include escaping characters. Conclusion - parse data in app. Second option - use serialization with scalar CLR to xml and use xquery on sqlserver. Example: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQLCLR/74160/

Comment: Wow, that's some complex stuff there @Deadsheep39. The reason I'm needing to do this is that it's a custom report I'm building where the user on the front-end needs the ability to select the columns they wish to return in the report.

Comment: I don't know that it has to be as complicated as @Deadshepp39 implies. Certainly I would also suggest parsing on the application side. That is return all columns and decide what to show in the app side. There is more data traffic but less to go wrong with dynamic SQL (in particular, sql injection). The dynamic SQL you have is the only solution for this but you are right to be suspicious of it. It's best avoided. SQL Server works best when it knows exactly what columns are being returned all the time.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts @Nick.McDermaid When are you say passed on the application side what are you referring to, as I'm not sure what would be passed to the stored procedure?

Comment: Based on your example: Your application runs `SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM Table` (i.e. every field). Then inside the application it decides (based on your user selection) what is actually shown. That's what I mean by par*s*ed. There is probably more to this than you've explained though.

Comment: I see what you mean @Nick.McDermaid. The problem is as you thought it is a bit more complex where the user needs to have the ability to choose whether to group by and count/sum/average on any of the fields. It overall becomes quite a messy complex dynamic SQL set but I'm really stuck on how to approach it nicely.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is always complicated. It doesn't have the performance benefits of a cached plan either. Another way is to try and build it in LINQ instead (I can't believe I suggested that). Maybe this is of interest: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library That way, you can include your complex logic in your app, and a real SQL query is submitted to the database.

Comment: I find some json to xml converter https://sqlsunday.com/2013/05/12/converting-json-data-to-xml-using-a-t-sql-function/ which can help you (but better (=much more faster) way is clr function). You can cast json string to xml and then use xquery to get data. If you can more description add please more real example strings and i'll create longer answer with guide.

Comment: Thanks for your continued input @Nick.McDermaid. Appreciate it. Haha, LINQ. I share a similar opinion :)  At least I haven't missed something obvious so thanks

Comment: Thanks very much @Deadsheep39. I've just made an edit to the main post with all the possible json variable values.

Comment: It's always only header without data? Real json string can be something like {"Person": {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith","age": [25, 26, 27] ...}}

Comment: Just checked @Deadsheep39 and its actually like this what is being passed: [\"FirstName\",\"LastName\",\"GenderID\"]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case (your json string contain only header with column names) and used for column selection only so it's easy. It's much more harder if you would like get values from json string too.

**Variant 1:** Use system table to validate your input and get column names.

```
declare @json varchar(800) = '["FirstName", "LastName", "DOB","DrugName,"Age","AgeGroup", "Overdose","VerificationCode","Gender"]',
@columnames varchar(800)

select @columnames = isnull(@sql + ', ', name) + name
from (
    select name, '"' + name + '"' name_quoted
    from sys.columns c
    where object_id('dbo.Client') = object_id) t
where @json like '%' + name_quoted + '%'

print @columnames
exec ('select ' + @columnames + ' from dbo.Client')
```

**Variant 2:** Working with strings.

```
declare @json varchar(800) = '["FirstName", "LastName","DOB","DrugName,"Age","AgeGroup","Overdose","VerificationCode","Gender"]';
declare @sql varchar(max) = replace(substring(@json, 2, len(@json) - 2), '"','')
print @sql
exec ('select ' + @sql + ' from dbo.Client')
```