# SQL Server: Dynamically create Column Names from JSON Auto Data

Tags: .net, json, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I created JSON Data with JSONAUTO in SQL Server.

```
   SELECT *
   from #Testdata
   FOR JSON AUTO
```

Its stored in nvarchar(max), and create multiple records of the same type.

```
[{"ProductId":1,"ProductName":"Food","ProductDescription":"Apple","DatePurchased":"1995-05-01T00:00:00"},   {"ProductId":2,"ProductName":"Electronics","ProductDescription":"TV","DatePurchase":"2018-09-17T00:00:00"}]
```

Now I want to insert into Tablename with Exact same Column names as Json Fields.
Trying to Dynamically create the column names, to insert into table with exact same column names. How would I conduct this with SQL Server Json library?

```
insert into dbo.SampleTable
(
      ProductId,
      ProductName, 
      ProductDescription, 
      DatePurchased
)
```

Now allowed to Explicity state the column numes, from typing, column names must be derived from Json data itself. Will have future types of data later.

**Update:**

Reading this answer, wondering if there is a way to bypass removing first and last letter, doesn't SQL server have an internal library function? This is what I am looking for, while eliminating the substring stuff, which is removing brackets [  and ].

[SQL Server - Using JSON to return Column Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423713/sql-server-using-json-to-return-column-names)

```
declare @json NVARCHAR(MAX)  = '[{"ProductId":1,"ProductName":"Food","ProductDescription":"Apple","DatePurchased":"1995-05-01T00:00:00"},   {"ProductId":2,"ProductName":"Electronics","ProductDescription":"TV","DatePurchase":"2018-09-17T00:00:00"}]'

DECLARE @jsonformatted NVARCHAR(MAX) =  substring(@json, 2, len(@json)-1)
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@jsonformatted);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    DECLARE @jsonata NVARCHAR(MAX)='[{"ProductId":1,"ProductName":"Food","ProductDescription":"Apple","DatePurchase":"1995-05-01T00:00:00"},   {"ProductId":2,"ProductName":"Electronics","ProductDescription":"TV","DatePurchase":"2018-09-17T00:00:00"}]'

DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)=N' INSERT INTO [TableName] ('

SELECT @Query+=T.ColumnName+','
FROM
(    
SELECT   y.[key] AS ColumnName,
         x.[Key]                                    
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonata) x
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(x.[value])) y
) AS T
WHERE T.[Key]=0


SET @Query=STUFF(@Query,LEN(@Query),1,' ')+' ) VALUES ('


SELECT @Query+=''''+T.Value+''''+
       (CASE WHEN ISNULL(LEAD(T.[Key]) OVER(ORDER BY T.[Key]),0)=T.[Key] THEN ',' ELSE '),(' END) 
FROM
(
SELECT   y.[key] AS ColumnName,
         y.[Value],
         X.[key]
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonata) x
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(x.[value])) y
) AS T

SET @Query=SUBSTRING(@Query,1,LEN(@Query)-2)

--Print Query Statment
PRINT (@Query)

EXEC(@Query)

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpNKc.png
```

Comment: this just makes the answer more complicated, the point is to Simplify answer in question above

Answer (score 3):

**Explanations:**

If you don't know the column names, you need to use `OPENJSON()` with [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/use-openjson-with-the-default-schema-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) schema to return a table with one row for each property of the object or for each element in the array. In your case you may try to query the first item of your `JSON` data.

T-SQL:

```
SELECT [key] 
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$[0]')
```

Output:

```
-------------------
key
-------------------
ProductId
ProductName
ProductDescription
DatePurchase
```

**Example:**

If you need more complex data manipulation, you may try to generate and execute a dynamic statement:

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'
   [    
    {
    "ProductId":1,
    "ProductName":"Food",
    "ProductDescription":"Apple",
    "DatePurchased":"1995-05-01T00:00:00"
    },   
    {
    "ProductId":2,
    "ProductName":"Electronics",
    "ProductDescription":"TV",
    "DatePurchased":"2018-09-17T00:00:00"
    }
   ]   
'
```

Dynamic INSERT statement:

```
DECLARE @columns nvarchar(max) = N''
DECLARE @schema nvarchar(max) = N''
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)

-- Columns
SELECT 
   @columns = CONCAT(@columns, N',', QUOTENAME([key])),
   @schema = CONCAT(@schema, N',', QUOTENAME([key]), N' varchar(max) ''$.', [key], N'''')
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$[0]')

-- Statement
SET @stm = CONCAT(
   N'INSERT INTO #TestData (',
   STUFF(@columns, 1, 1, N''),
   N') SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (',
   STUFF(@schema, 1, 1, N''),   
   N') json'
)

PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```

Generated statement:

```
INSERT INTO #TestData ([ProductId],[ProductName],[ProductDescription],[DatePurchased])
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
   [ProductId] varchar(max) '$.ProductId',
   [ProductName] varchar(max) '$.ProductName',
   [ProductDescription] varchar(max) '$.ProductDescription',
   [DatePurchased] varchar(max) '$.DatePurchased'
) json
```

**Original answer:**

If I understand you correctly, you need to use `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema definition.

Statement:

```
INSERT INTO #TestData
   (ProductId, ProductName, ProductDescription, DatePurchased)
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
   ProductId varchar(100) '$.ProductId',
   ProductName varchar(100) '$.ProductName', 
   ProductDescription varchar(100) '$.ProductDescription', 
   DatePurchased datetime '$.DatePurchased'
) json
```

Comment: hi, not exactly what I am looking for, I cannot Directly Explicit state the column names, they must be dynamic,I will be reading variable column names later, will restate in question, thanks

Comment: @MattSmith I've made an update. Probably a dynamic statement is more appropriate in this case. Thanks.

Comment: this just makes the answer more complicated, the point is to Simplify answer in question above

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the array brackets around it, then you may want

SELECT *
from #Testdata
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER

But, be aware that if you get multiple rows, that would be invalid JSON.

See Microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/remove-square-brackets-from-json-without-array-wrapper-option?view=sql-server-ver15